# How to combine standard deviations using variance?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

I only know that Variance is $  SD^2  $ and do not understand how it comes into the picture and so do not know if this answer is correct. Can someone please confirm whether it is correct?

> **Question**: A particular process has two independent sources of
>   variation. The standard deviation of the first source is 3 units and
>   the standard deviation of the second source is 4 units. The standard
>   deviation of the process is which of the following?

...

> **Answer**: Find the variance of all standard deviations by squaring each
>   (3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25), then take the square root of 25 which is 5.
>   By squaring each individual standard deviation (SD), you get the
>   variance. By adding up the variances then taking the square root of
>   that sum, you can assign a SD for the process as a whole.